# Бесконечный цикл

Tags: c

При заданном натуральном N вычислить сумму:

> S = 1 / sin (1) + 1 / (sin (1) + sin (2)) + ... + 1 / (sin (1) + sin (2) + ... + sin (N))

```
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  float S, d;
  printf("Введите число: \n");
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++ )
  {
    ...
  }

  printf("Сумма S = %f”, S);
  return 0;
}
```

Помогите задать ему значение `sin 1` и засунуть его в цикл.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
float S;
int n;
printf("Введите число: n");
int i;
for ( i = 1; i<=N; i ++ ) { ... }
printf("Сумма S = %f”, S); return 0; }
```

нельзя считать sin(N) количество раз,поскольку это врядли будет целое число да и вообще..
синус из введенного числа вам нужно будет посчитать в коде который вы сюда не скинули 
{ ... }

Comment: разве что так :
int n;
printf("Введите число: n");
int i;
n=sin(1); //но тогда теряется ввесь смысл введения числа!!
for ( i = 1; i<=n; i ++ ) { ... }

Comment: спасибо большое за удочку,рыбку я попробую поймать сам:)

Answer (score 1):

Если рыбка не ловится:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

float Polynom(int N);

void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "RUS");
    int N = 0;
    float fSum = 0;
    puts("Enter N:");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 1; i<=N; i++)
        fSum += Polynom(i);
    printf("\nСумма S = %f\n", fSum);
    system("pause");
}

float Polynom(int N)
{
    float fSinSum=0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=N; i++)
        fSinSum += sin( (float)i );
    return 1 / fSinSum;
}
```

Comment: Это если я правильно понял условие и знаменатель одночлена (sin1 + sin2 + ... + sinN) (в знаменателе сумма всех членов). Вот только потеря точности громадная, лучше использовать тип double.

Comment: дааа,ничего не получилось=(
но вот то что написал вы,я половину пока не понимаю команд...

Comment: У меня все получается. А если не понимаете команды, надо прочитать хорошие книги, или задать вопрос, Вам объяснят. Тем более, что в данной программе я использовал минимум новых функций, Вы должны их знать.

Comment: Для ALEX_LAY_PRO: сумму следует сохранять, а не начинать каждый раз вычисления ее заново.

Comment: Для @BuilderC: если Вы о функции Polynom(int N), то это не общая сумма, а сумма **синусов в знаменателе**. Сама же сумма-ответ имеется в переменной fSum в ф-кции main().

Comment: Я и говорю о ней - о сумме синусов в знаменателе

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду, что следует реализовать сумму не моим способом, а каждый раз добавлять очередной синус, то

1) У меня наиболее простой и удобочитаемый вариант;

2) В функции Polynom(int) я считаю очередной член суммы. В случае ошибки мне не надо лазить по всему коду, а лишь изменить одну функцию;

3) То, что сделал я, предотвращает потерю точности.

4) Реализуйте более гибкий и точный вариант, и он будет принят. Да и лишние 15 очков не повредят...

Answer (score 0):

double Polynom(double &SSin, int N) 
{ 
  SSin += sin(N);
  return 1 / SSin; 
} 
в main инициализируете double SSin = 0.0; Передаете значение в Polynom. 
В пунктах 2 и 3 написаны милые глупости.

Answer (score 0):

Ну хоть и древность неимоверная, но написанный в ответах ужас не дает промолчать :)

```
double sinsum(unsigned int N)
{
    double partial_sum = 0.0, sum = 0.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        sum += 1.0/(partial_sum += sin(i));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

А то начинают тут по `N` раз `sin(1)` вычислять... :)